# javascript objects identical but not equal. how is this possible?

Tags: javascript

i am working with js right now.

i have two objects `left` and `right`.

if i check `console.log(left !== right)` i get `true`.

now if i check `console.log(typeof(left) !== typeof(right))` i get `false`.

now if i check `console.log(left != right)` i get `true`.

if i check both objects in `https://www.jsondiff.com/` it says both objects are identical.

how is this possible? i am so confused. can someone help on what could be the possible reason this is happening?

sorry i cannot share exact objects.

Comment: Object equality is a different topic altogether in JavaScript. If you are using `===` operator, if both objects are referring to exact same memory location, then only it is going to evaluated as true. If you comparing objects, i.e. comparing all the values of an Object, iterate through all the properties in an object and perform comparison. Or you may use some helper library like lodash.

Comment: What you observe will happen for _any_ two objects, unless one has been assigned to the other (by setting `left = right`). Otherwise they are neither equal nor identical (which amounts to the same for objects), but their `typeof` is "object".

Comment: `{} === {}` and `{} == {}` are both `false` in JavaScript. You can't use `==` or `===` to compare objects, you have to iterate over their properties and compare them.